# Circulation and the flux in a field

Tags: multivariable-calculus, solution-verification

Problem:

> Find the circulation and flux of the field $F=x^2i+y^2j$ around and across the closed semicircular path that consists of the semicircular arch $r_1(t)=(a\cos(t))i+(a\sin(t))j$, $0\le t\le\pi$, followed by the line segment $r_2(t)=ti$, $-a\le t\le a$.

Then I compute the followings:

$r_1(t)=(a\cos(t))i+(a\sin(t))j\implies r_1'(t)=(-a\sin(t))i+(a\cos(t))j$

$F(r_1(t))=(a^2\cos^2t)i+(a^2\sin^2t)j$

$F(r_1(t))\cdot r_1'(t)=-a^3\sin t\cos^2 t+a^3\sin^2t\cos t$

Circulation along $r_1=\int_{-a}^aa^3(\sin^2 t\cos t-\sin t\cos^2t)dt=\frac{2}{3}a^3\sin^3a$

Flux along $r_1=\int_0^{\pi}(a\cos t)(a\cos t)-(a\sin t)(-a\sin t)dt=a^2\pi$

$r_2(t)=ti\implies r_2'(t)=i$

$F(r_2(t))=t^2i$

$F(r_2(t))\cdot r_2'(t)=t^2$

Circulation along $r_2=\int_{-a}^at^2dt=\frac{2}{3}a^3$

Flux along $r_2=\int_{-a}^a(t(0)-(0)(1))dt=0$

Hence the total circulation$=\frac{2}{3}a^3\sin^3a+\frac{2}{3}a^3=\frac{2}{3}a^3(1+\sin^3a)$, and the total flux$=a^2\pi+0=a^2\pi$.

My questions are:

1. Are my computations valid? (I mean the steps here, not the arithmetics)
2. It seems that the calculation of the flux is independent of the field. Is that normal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The total circulation should be **zero** because $\mathbf{F}$ is a conservative field,
$\nabla U=\mathbf{F}$ with $U(x,y)=\frac{x^3}{3}+\frac{y^3}{3}$, and the path is closed.

In your work, the limits of the integral for $r_1$ should be $0$ and $\pi$ (not $-a$ and $a$),
$$\int_{0}^\pi a^3(\sin^2 t\cos t-\sin t\cos^2t)dt=-\frac{2a^3}{3}.$$

By the divergence theorem, the total flux is
$$\iint_{D} (2x+2y)dxdy=0+2\iint_{D} ydxdy=2\int_{r=0}^a\int_{\theta=0}^{\pi}r^2\sin(\theta)dr d\theta=\frac{4a^3}{3}$$
where $D$ is the semidisc $\{(x,y): x^2+y^2\leq a^2, y\geq 0\}.$

In your work, the flux accross $r_1$ should be (you missed the squares),
$$\int_0^{\pi}(a\cos t)^2(a\cos t)+(a\sin t)^2(a\sin t)dt=\frac{4a^3}{3}.$$

Comment: Got it. Thanks for your help!